# Haskell cabal issue with Mac OS X 10.11? (cannot satisfy -package-id)

Tags: macos, haskell, osx-elcapitan

I used the latest Haskell Platform 7.10.2-a (https://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html) on Mac OS X 10.11 for El-capitan.

When I tried to install `yesod` with `cabal install yesod`, I have multiple error messages such as:

```
Building email-validate-2.1.3...
Building http-api-data-0.2.1...
Building fast-logger-2.4.1...
Building http-date-0.0.6.1...
Failed to install crypto-random-0.0.9
Build log ( /Users/smcho/.cabal/logs/crypto-random-0.0.9.log ):
Configuring crypto-random-0.0.9...
Building crypto-random-0.0.9...
Preprocessing library crypto-random-0.0.9...
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id vector-0.11.0.0-730f99979d41c11c3a1ef069844b5f57
    (use -v for more information)
Failed to install email-validate-2.1.3
Build log ( /Users/smcho/.cabal/logs/email-validate-2.1.3.log ):
Configuring email-validate-2.1.3...
```

The error pattern is pretty much the same: `cannot satisfy -package-id`.

For example, `cabal install aeson` gives `cannot satisfy -package-id attoparse...` error.

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring aeson-0.10.0.0...
Building aeson-0.10.0.0...
Failed to install aeson-0.10.0.0
Build log ( /Users/smcho/.cabal/logs/aeson-0.10.0.0.log ):
Configuring aeson-0.10.0.0...
Building aeson-0.10.0.0...
Preprocessing library aeson-0.10.0.0...
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id attoparsec-0.13.0.1-99b4df28644e63383f308c810764a8bb
    (use -v for more information)
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
aeson-0.10.0.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

However, attoparsec library seems to be installed without problem.

```
smcho@macho ~> cabal install attoparsec
Resolving dependencies...
All the requested packages are already installed:
attoparsec-0.13.0.1
Use --reinstall if you want to reinstall anyway.
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: I'd suggest two things: a) drop haskell platform and just install via `brew`. b)  Use stack(age).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be controversial, but imho the haskell platform and cabal (when used directly) are both essentially deprecated now with the advent of [stack](https://www.stackage.org/).

Stack will:

1. Automatically install haskell for you (`stack setup`)
2. Automatically sandbox (and intelligently share sandboxes between projects)
3. Completely avoid cabal hell (in my experience)

Answer (score 3):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139263/cabal-install-failing-osx-many-unsatisfied-packages), the `cannot satisfy -package-id` error you're seeing might be due to an out of date cache.

If running `ghc-pkg check` warns you that your cache is out of date, then running `ghc-pkg recache` might resolve your issues.

I've been running into the `cannot satisfy -package-id` problem all morning (not with yesod, but with various other packages). `ghc-pkg recache` resolved my issues. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I could install yesod from brew.

#### Uninstall haskell-plaftorm

- `/Library/Haskell/bin/uninstall-hs thru 7.10.2`

#### Install ghc

- `brew install ghc`

  - `brew link ghc`

#### Install stackage

- `brew install haskell-stack`

#### Install Yesod

- `stack install yesod`
- `stack install yesod-bin`

#### Use Yesod

- [Getting "Could not find module `Yesod'" when I try to run first example from Yesod book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200773/getting-could-not-find-module-yesod-when-i-try-to-run-first-example-from-yes)

  - `stack runghc hello-world.hs`

#### Use Yesod for development

- I'm not sure, but I had to run `stack exec yesod build` first.
- `stack exec yesod devel`.

#### Yesod deployment with keter

- Remove the first line in config/keter.yaml
- `stack exec yesod keter`, and you will get one binary in dist/bin that contains most of the necessary files to run.
- Execute the binary as a standalone server.

Comment: You're conflating Stackage with Stack in your answer. They are different but related things.